# What is the subterms of $M\equiv (\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z \cdot x(yx))$?

Tags: logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus

Using this

Definition (**Subterms**): The **subterms** of a term M are defined by induction on $|M|$ as follows:

1. an atom is a subterm of itself;
2. if $M\equiv \lambda x \cdot P$, its subterms are $M$ and all subterms of $P$;
3. if $M \equiv P_1 P_2$, its subterms are all the subterms of $P_1$, all those of $P_2$, and $M$ itself.

Example: If $M\equiv (\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z \cdot  x(yx))$ its subterms are $x$, $y$, $yx$, $\lambda x \cdot yx$, $x(yx)$, $\lambda z \cdot x(yx)$ and M itself. (But not $z$.)

So, my question is: why $z$ is not a subterm in the given example?

Comment: Because $z$ is not a sub-term of $x(yx)$.

Comment: So, $x(yx)$ is like $P$ in definition number 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly--it's the part to the right of the "$\lambda x.$"

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Depends on definition of set of Subterms, If you think $z$ should be a Subterm, you may change the definition as you like:

1. $\dots$;
2. $M \equiv \lambda x \cdot P$, its Subterms are $M$, $x$ and all Subterms of $P$;
3. $\dots$.

This may make sense to you as you want $z$ to be a subset of the term you mentioned, but with the definition you provided, it's simple to just go step by step and compute the set of Subterms.

$\text{sub}((\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx)))$

(by rule 3.)

$=\{(\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx))\} \cup \text{sub}(\lambda x\cdot yx) \cup \text{sub}(\lambda z\cdot x(yx))$

(by rule 2.) (Note here we loose $z$)

$=\{(\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx))\} \cup \{\lambda x\cdot yx\} \cup \text{sub}(yx) \cup \{\lambda z\cdot x(yx)\} \cup \text{sub}(x(yx))$

(simplification)

$=\{(\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx)), \lambda x\cdot yx, \lambda z\cdot x(yx)\} \cup \text{sub}(yx) \cup \text{sub}(x(yx))$

(by rule 3.)

$=\{(\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx)), \lambda x\cdot yx, \lambda z\cdot x(yx)\}  \cup \{yx\} \cup \text{sub}(y) \cup \text{sub}(x) \cup \{x(yx)\} \cup \text{sub}(x) \cup \{yx\} \cup \text{sub}(y) \cup \text{sub}(x)$

(simplification)

$=\{(\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx)), \lambda x\cdot yx, \lambda z\cdot x(yx), yx\} \cup \text{sub}(y) \cup \text{sub}(x)  \cup \text{sub}(x) \cup \text{sub}(y) \cup \text{sub}(x)$

(by rule 1.)

$=\{(\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx)), \lambda x\cdot yx, \lambda z\cdot x(yx), yx\} \cup \{y\} \cup \{x\} \cup \{x\} \cup \{y\} \cup \{x\}$

(simplification)

$=\{(\lambda x\cdot yx)(\lambda z\cdot x(yx)), \lambda x\cdot yx, \lambda z\cdot x(yx), yx, y, x\}$

Comment: I wrote down your proof and I really enjoyed it.
However, I didn't understand why $x(yx)$ was not considered a subterm.
Furthermore, I could not understand why a term accompanied by $\lambda$ is not considered a subterm (if I look at rule 2), because rule 2 for me is little bit ambiguous: It says that $M \equiv \lambda x \cdot P$, its subterms are $M$ and all subterms of $P$; (So my question is: Why $ \lambda x$ is not a sub term of $M$?)

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova the term $x(yx)$ is indeed a Subterm, it was omitted the second time in the set as sets do not repeat elements.

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova $\lambda x$ is not a Subterm of $M$ since there are only two ways for a term to be a Subterm of $M$, first being the $M$ itself, and second being Subterm of $P$, non of them is possible, the second one is not possible because $P$ doesn't contain $\lambda x$. Also, $\lambda x$ is not a valid term at all, any term is of form $P_1P_2$ or $\lambda x \cdot P$.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me very much!!

Comment: You're welcome.